# Replace final comma in a string with "and"

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I've got a string that is generated, and is essentially a list of things. This string is something that will be read by the user, so I'm trying to formate it nicely. I am separating the generated list using commas and spaces:

```
(a+'').replace(/,/g, ", ");
```

produces

```
1, 2, 3, 4
```

However, I'd like to change the last comma to ", and", so that it reads

```
1, 2, 3, and 4
```

I've tried the following:

```
((a+'').replace(/,/g, ", ")).replace(/,$/, ", and");
```

but it doesn't work, which I THINK is because that is only looking for commas at the end of the string, rather than the last comma in the string, right?

As well, if there are only 2 items in the string, I want the comma to be replaced with just "and", rather than ", and", to make more sense grammatically.

How can I achieve what I'm looking for?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You probably want

```
,(?=[^,]+$)
```

for example:

```
"1, 2, 3, 4".replace(/,(?=[^,]+$)/, ', and');
```

`(?=[^,]+$)` checks that there are no more commas after this comma. `(?!.*,)` would also work.

You can even check there isn't already an `and`:

```
,(?!\s+and\b)(?=[^,]+$)
```

Working example: https://regex101.com/r/aE2fY7/2

Comment: Performance question: which regex would perform better between your one and @Toto one?

Comment: @ColOfAbRiX - I'd guess vks's one was faster, we can even drop the capturing group (replace with `$&`). In my experience regex is relatively slow, so if performance is really important a short string manipulation would be better.

Answer (score 6):

```
(.*,)
```

You can use this simple regex.Replace by `$1 and` or `\1 and`.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/uE3cC4/8

```
var re = /(.*,)/gm;
var str = '1, 2, 3, 4';
var subst = '$1 and';

var result = str.replace(re, subst);
```

Comment: I'm replacing the last comma by and based on your answer. Thank you!['first','sporty','system'].join(', ').replace( /(.*)\,/gm, '$1 and')

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
((a+'').replace(/,/g, ", ")).replace(/,([^,]*)$/, ", and $1");
```

Answer (score -1):

```
var index = a.lastIndexOf(',');
a.replaceAt(index, ', and');
```

where  :

```
String.prototype.replaceAt=function(index, character) {
    return this.substr(0, index) + character + this.substr(index+character.length);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You could try

```
list1=[]
list2=[1, 2, 3, 4]
list2Str=(str(list2).replace("[","").replace("]","").replace("'",""))
for i in range (0,len(list2Str)):
  if list2Str[i] == ',':
    list1.append(i)
list1.sort(reverse=True)
list2Str = list2Str[:list1[0]] + ' and' + list2Str[list1[0]+1:]
print (list2Str)
```

A bit long-winded but it works and is fairly simple